Playwright test not running in parallel
I have a single Playwright test setup to run multiple times with different parameters.
const chars = [
  {name: "John"},
  {name: "Jane"},
];


chars.forEach(async char => {
  test(`Test for ${char.name}`, async ({ page }) => {
    await runTest(page, char.name);
  });
});

I have a list of characters, which a test is run for each. However, these tests happen in sequence and not in parallel. They are all in one file.
In the playwright.config.js fullyParallel: true, on each project such as chromium and  it is also set to true in defineConfig.
If you need more information, please ask. How can I run these in parallel?

What value do you have for workers in your playwright config?

workers: process.env.CI ? 1 : undefined, which was the default. But I have tried changing it and it always runs with 1 worker.
